# Installing Ubuntu without external media, UEFI for recent versions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a new laptop, on which I would like to setup a dual-boot configuration with Windows 10. Windows 10 is installed on the main SSD, and I plan to install Ubuntu on the 1TB external HDD by creating a partition for it and installing Grub on that drive. I do not, however, have any external media such as a USB drive and this laptop lacks a CD drive. How can I boot the live installation media? Also, my laptop cannot use EasyBCD, as this uses UEFI and I'd prefer to not have to format the drive to boot an ISO file using it. Is there any way this could be possible? I wondered about installing Grub on the hard drive, and then using Grub's commands to boot an ISO file from a partition on the drive, but I have no idea whether this would work.

Comment: I just saw on a Microcenter web site, that a USB3 flash drive 16GB is $3.00. It is so much easier to use a flash drive that it is worth the 3 dollars. Once I have grub installed, I keep one partition on every drive just for ISO and have grub configured to directly boot ISO. So ISO on SSD is for install to sdb & vice-versa. UEFI install to second drive is an issue. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1229488

Comment: @oldfred in all honesty, i could buy it, but its more to see if its possible at all

Comment: Two issues, grub install & partitioning. I do not know how to install an UEFI bootable copy of grub to ESP for direct booting and Windows partitioning tools will not create ext4 partitions. You could try creating a larger FAT32 partition so you can extract Ubuntu ISO on SSD. Temporarily move boot flag to that new partition, so UEFI sees that as bootable partition. Not sure if you can have that on sdb, and still install to sdb as the unmount popup usually does not work, toram parameter may help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: How about going into Windows, opening a command prompt, and run `diskpart` then `list disk` and `exit'? Dollars to doughnuts, your SSD is UEFI already.